# Yii2 LinkedIn authentication issue

Tags: php, yii2

In my yii2 project I used Authclient function to call Api logins like Facebook/Google and LinkedIn.
and in my controller I get the attributes and redirecting it to my custom pages.
**My Controller**

```
public function successCallback($client)
{
    $attributes = $client->getUserAttributes();
      $user_email = $attributes['email'];
    $user_name = $attributes['name'];
    $user = User::find()->where(['user_email'=>$user_email])->one();
    $count = count($user);
    if ($count == 0 ){
        return $this->redirect(['user/create?email='.$user_email.'&name='.$user_name.'']);
    }else{
        return Yii::$app->user->login($user);

    }
}
```

Facebook and Google are working perfectly but LinkedIn is not not retriving any attributes .It only gives some code like **AQTq1AlTvyS-3rqGBT5mZE5-Vw4gybfeZ8kK3lBf2UhdSjvrLlokNwnd_vGXEPrlEg8to8KH-AQfYZPlu4yIqObDwpJhuWFScpd1yRNrt4Y0Q**

How can I decode this code to get the user details. Can anybody help me with this?

Comment: in which form you are getting the code

Comment: check this https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/oauth2

Comment: AQRTnq8dq-qgRe3ecEIxm-ZXHaR0hUuaVjJq1NYtopp82FuwHJijHDHkil-TZT51ucRKUj4GRLuG6LFzCY5KQz_JrqFuylOXBOUKHfQ-CSWKME.
this is foramte I got